# Random Trees in OpenCV with Python (load method missing)

Tags: python, opencv

In OpenCV 3.2.0 with Python can't find load function to load pre-trained model, it's clearly explained in C++ `StatModel::load<RTrees>(filename)`. How to load pre-trained model with Python?

```
>>> import cv2

>>> help(cv2.ml.RTrees_create())

....
 |  clear(...)
 |      clear() -> None
 |  
 |  getDefaultName(...)
 |      getDefaultName() -> retval
 |  
 |  save(...)
 |      save(filename) -> None
```

load(...) missing?

Comment: Yah, you can [see](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/05b15943d6a42c99e5f921b7dbaa8323f3c042c6/modules/core/include/opencv2/core.hpp#L3055) there's no `CV_WRAP` before this function, which is necessary for it to be wrapped in the Python API. Most likely due to it being a template. If you look in [`ml.cpp`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/05b15943d6a42c99e5f921b7dbaa8323f3c042c6/modules/ml/include/opencv2/ml.hpp) you can see that few of the derived classes provide an implementation of `load()` and wrap it too. Looks like it hasn't been done for RTrees...

Comment: Thanks for answer. That is sad that there is no wrap for Python. Do you what is possible walk around? To use cv2.FileStorage('ore-trained-model.xml',cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ)?

Comment: At this point I'm not really sure how to get around it easily. I'd definitely suggest checking the OpenCV issue tracker (on github), and if it's not there, create a ticket about this. | If you can patch your OpenCV, maybe the simplest thing to do would be to CV_WRAP [`Algorithm::read(...)`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/05b15943d6a42c99e5f921b7dbaa8323f3c042c6/modules/core/include/opencv2/core.hpp#L3020).